# How many lattice points are on the boundary or inside the region bounded by $y=|x|$ and $y=-x^2+6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems, integer-lattices

A lattice point is a point whose coordinates are both integers. How many lattice points are on the boundary or inside the region bounded by $y=|x|$ and $y=-x^2+6$?

I thought there were two points, but that isn't right. What am I missing?

Comment: Draw the graphs. Where do they intersect? (do that part algebraically). Now look at the graphs. What are the possible values of $x$ that need to be tested? For each such value of $x$, find the qualifying $y$-values.

Comment: Thanks to Pick's theorem we can give a rough estimate of the area between the parabola and the lines, which is $A\approx i+b/2-1$ where $i$ are the points inside the region and $b$ the points on the boundary. We get $A\approx 14$ where actual area is $\dfrac{44}{3}\approx 14.6$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remark(I)**: The two equations intersects at $(\pm 2, 2)$.

**Remark(II)**: The points $(\pm 2, 2); \  (\pm 1, 5); \ (0, 6)$ lies 
on the boundary of the parabola $y=-x^2+6$.

**Remark(III)**: The points $(\pm 2, 2); \  (\pm 1, 1); \ (0, 0)$ lies 
on the boundary of $y= | x |$.

---

**Remark(IV)**: Consider the line $y=1$; 
we know that the point $(1,5)$ 
lies on the boundary of the parabola $y=-x^2+6$; 
also 
we know that the point $(1,1)$ 
lies on the boundary of $y= | x |$.
So all the other lattice points , between these two points; 
which lies on the line $y=1$; are in the interior, 
i.e. all the points $(1, 2); \ (1, 3); \ (1, 4)$ are in the interior.

**Remark(V)**: Consider the line $y=-1$; 
we know that the point $(-1,5)$ 
lies on the boundary of the parabola $y=-x^2+6$; 
also 
we know that the point $(-1,1)$ 
lies on the boundary of $y= | x |$.
So all the other lattice points , between these two points; 
which lies on the line $y=-1$; are in the interior, 
i.e. all the points $(-1, 2); \ (-1, 3); \ (-1, 4)$ are in the interior.

---

**Remark(VI)**: Consider the line $y=0$; 
we know that the point $(0,6)$ 
lies on the boundary of the parabola $y=-x^2+6$; 
also 
we know that the point $(0,0)$ 
lies on the boundary of $y= | x |$.
So all the other lattice points , between these two points; 
which lies on the line $y=0$; are in the interior, 
i.e. all the points 
$(0, 1); \ (0, 2); \ (0, 3) \ (0, 4); \ (0, 5); $ are in the interior.

---

---

---

---

The points on the boundary of are as follows:
$$(\pm 2, 2); \  (\pm 1, 5); \ (0, 6); 
\\ 
(\pm 1, 1); \ (0, 0).  $$

---

The interior points are as follows:
$$(\pm 1, 2); \ (\pm 1, 3); \ (\pm 1, 4); 
\\ 
(0, 1); \ (0, 2); \ (0, 3); \ (0, 4); \ (0,5).  $$

---

So there are $19$ such points.

Comment: So there are 19 lattice points in total?

Comment: @ddswsd ; yes there are exactly $19$ lattice points in total.

Comment: This has been very helpful! I originally thought it was just points of intersection, this is much more interesting. Thank you!